# Expecting json response from recaptcha but getting some long string?

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

I'm suppose to be getting a json object response from google recaptcha (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) but I'm just getting a huge string of letters/numbers.

Am I missing something?

**Additional info:**

- I'm using https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha
- I'm using localhost currently
- This isn't one of the exact responses, but as an example:

03AHJ_Vuswy-TQzBlVYNOGdelLhl0YsRMKGBD-Zu6ETlJNor1HMyksXtGRmWaBbx7kgDrmT64_pYEbs5U-uHLHwBYSsRb4idin9Q5yabG6UueG-Uw8dIqxA_C1hJB0NJ8i-hKG3tmllsIGojj39ZHRXR3CnghL0UkFaHVOHyVqTlFq31SS9o-OR8JpJG7osy6HStTGs6LT1IX9iea0V1pm43aRqtoSgZWvbxGE2B7HvCGchc74wk_tcomA9W4aYouoFqzG3_Ol4PY8ZJz_VJZkDCN0qhbWqWvm96122QSumRkOGtVg1AFaMiYJgQOSt8neggdegnxJo70Mw94H8eEGNxbOokOqLJrFUDAY-9gEYdGEQKsgfm3V9hFvClUkPg_XBZSQWY1kaaRJvkqWt47gy0h3N5_7WJnQX2DAyG2vscM-BKmH0kmo4OEhpI2QCB3t0ESrBZcahIfSBiQkOL7xcSOq-R53MY4mPLVteDq78jhJiu0ZKF95UUVbJ7y9m_xTBzlk9KAWYCDbvpavgBXjKPkz3YRgJPWe8I5onDkSEIlhHFPpYu4zYvlk-phWFri4LkeUCQbcnqkTUmkVVpJpvWS0jqeMgKM-GKjXTEVxG6A5ak5xRCZtK-3NJYGwuWikCmxv8lEE22yl2CaD9XxOG38ONiyF_3SvW5ClPC3i1iy5fBkdwjEf_aIpZfpeE0Sv_0MHDgVz-2kf5kK5pgZAObiHvvHev9UZBzrhtDsinVjI0BlyuoG0znOVkrWyEAG5RCbX-mECfogFtc22fdsafsafsafasfsafsafas2OkTCIb0Eaemk9XEZEn1vO5egHlPaUhNYElU74m2XVTICTrsXwfRHpT-_okADMfyxJ-1jQkaM4w19j3AReOFY6d_nE4k1h5MmzFfeuO-S7G6yOPEOQAR27mVkDZNtdyGJm11_ODzuDKihepTkHlXSg_2-8Ozz0M3JjMjPjj5DlbTKI2DXkqjZBNiyN2qbQ

When I should be getting:

```
{
  "success": true|false,
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

Comment: Try base64 on this.

Comment: Hi paul Thanks for taking the time to responed. I don't understand how to do that, can you elaborate? Am I decoding it like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: Essentially yes. And find out what kind of data shows up.

Comment: It ended up being I needed to send an HTTP to google with the key that was returned on the client. I thought it was all client-side for some reason. The need to do some server-side work wasn't very explicit in the https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha docs and I'd never used recaptcha before, so, lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

This needs a server-side HTTP call to google with the response you get from the captcha on the client.